# keep colored text from .docx to .tex using pandoc

Tags: color, conversion, pandoc, msword, convert

I use `pandoc` on a Mac to translate a `.docx` document to a `.tex` document. The problem is that some words in the `.docx` document are colored (not highlighted but colored letters) and `pandoc` doesn't recognize the color so in the `.tex` document all words appear black. I want it to automatically load the `color` package and translate a colored text into something like:

```
asdf \textcolor{red}{asdfasdf} asdfasdf.
```

In the end I want to find&replace the `\textcolor` commands e.g. by a custom cite-environment. If you have another idea to find&replace colored text in a Word document I will be satisfied as well. thanks

Comment: Export to LateX from Libreoffice can produce code as 
  `\textcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.2,0.2}{text}`  selecting the right options of the export window. However, at the end of day I will opt for pandoc or export as "very simple article" (without colors) in Libreoffice.

Comment: do you have an other idea to mark something in the docx-document to replace it later automaticly? I thought of marking text in bold face or underlined but these are only two possible environments. So an additional idea was to play with the fontsize, but this will be annoying to look at in the docx-document

Comment: Use some custom markup and then use `sed` (or similar) to convert the text yourself.  (This may make the .docx source less reader-friendly, but no more so than some people find (say) *TeX or markdown sources.)

Comment: If you do not use  cursive-italics  often, also *text*  in .docx-.odt documents can be also exported as `\emph{text}` (pandoc,abiword) or `\textit{text}` (libreoffice) that later could be replaced easily by `\cite{text}` or something else.

Comment: But guessing about  the real problem (write/read  without being disturbed too much by LaTeX code?) I would suggest write in markdown so you can write `*text*` or  directly `\emph{text}` to obtain `\emph{text}` in LaTeX, or mark with something else LaTeX command  that will be exported to LaTeX as is (e.g. `\xxxx{text}`  is exported just as `\xxxx{text}` but of course,  in this case in the markdown text you should also define what `\xxxx` does, just like in a LaTeX document).

Comment: The project is a book written by an 80+ years old professor using dragon natural speaking, which creates a word-file. 
I'm helping him getting the book ready for printing. I asked him to do me a favour by coloring the text (e. g. quotes, names, cited books...) so it's easier for me to translate it. There are already many cursive words, so to me the different coloring seemes to be the best solution for a "custom markup". But how can I get the color transformed into code?